# Using Entity Framework with monodroid?

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin.android

I have seen some docs around suggesting that monodroid could support Entity Manager. Is this true? I remember reading that monodroid was based on 2.0 framework, and entity framework seems to be a 3.5 and above tecnology so I'm a bit confused here. Do anybody have any experience with this?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: .NET 3.5 runs on the 2.0 runtime, so ftom that perspective it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after spending around an hour looking for this information, I foudn the answer as soon as I posted the message D.

It is not supported. Features available to monodroid can be checked here:

http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/375825-how-does-mono-compare-to-net-4-0-